# How to remove the duplicates for append in my html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have create javascript to calulate the total of ext. form json but I have problem is it append twice to #total div I don't know what cause maybe because of renderTable function.can someone help me ??[image]

HTML

```
     <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="poInfos">
               <h3 id="poInfo"></h3>
              <table data-role="table" id="productOrders"  data-mode="reflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Code</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                      <th>Qty.</th>
                      <th>Ext.</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>            
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>                    
              </table> 
               <div id="total">

               </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
  //render table view all PO for vendor 
        function renderTable(data){
            var $table = $('#productOrders tbody');
            var plist = data[0].pslList;
            for(var i in plist) {
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + plist[i].prodcd + '</td><td>' + plist[i].prodname + '</td><td class="dollars">' + numberToCurrency(plist[i].price) + '</td><td>' + plist[i].qty + '</td><td>' + numberToCurrency(plist[i].ext) + '</td></tr>');       
                $table.append(row);
                calculateTotal(data);
            }

        }

        //calculateTotal 
        function calculateTotal(data)
        {
            var $totalDiv = $('#total');
            var tax = 0.00;
            var sub = 0.00;
            var totalsub_tax = 0.00;
            var plist = data[0].pslList;
            for(var i in plist) {
              sub += plist[i].ext;
              totalsub_tax  = sub +tax;
            }
            $totalDiv.append("<strong>Sub:</strong>"+numberToCurrency(sub)+"<br/><strong>Total:</strong>"+numberToCurrency(totalsub_tax) +"<br/>");
        }

        //convert  numberToCurrency
    function numberToCurrency(amount) {

        var thousandsSeparator = ","
        var currencyNum = "";
        var amountString = amount.toString();
        var digits = amountString.split("");

        var countDigits = digits.length;
        var revDigits = digits.reverse();

        for(var i=0; i<countDigits; i++) {
            if ((i%3 == 0) && (i !=0)) {
                currencyNum += thousandsSeparator+revDigits[i];
            } else {
                currencyNum += digits[i];
            }
        };

        var revCurrency = currencyNum.split("").reverse().join("");

        var finalCurrency = "$"+revCurrency;

        return finalCurrency;
    }



});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the function calculateTotal() for EACH item instead of after the items have been dealt with.

```
for(var i in plist) {
    var row = $('<tr><td>' + plist[i].prodcd + '</td><td>' + plist[i].prodname + '</td><td class="dollars">' + numberToCurrency(plist[i].price) + '</td><td>' + plist[i].qty + '</td><td>' + numberToCurrency(plist[i].ext) + '</td></tr>');       
    $table.append(row);
    // not here calculateTotal(data);
}
calculateTotal(data); // here
```

Comment: This helped with an issue I was having, thank you 2013 version of @Popnoodles!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `calculateTotal(data)` is within the loop over `plist`. You should move it outside.